# category with no name in the class's .m file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

what does it mean to create a category like this: `@interface myClass () ... @end` **in the same class's `.m` file** ? this category may contain methods and properties, why not to add these methods and properties directly in the class's `.h` file ?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a workaround for Objective-C's lack of private methods. You put classes in there to hide them from users of the class. They can technically still use them (although they'll get a warning) but if they don't know about them, they probably won't.

Comment: why not add a name for it though ?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052233/iphone-obj-c-anonymous-category-or-private-category

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes i would do this when i had a private method.

Because,if the method not define in header,when you call it in implementation,you got a warning, (your method's code is above your invoked).

like this:`Instance method '-XXX' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

So,for no warning,i put a method define in a category maybe i will write a @interface myClass(private).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no name in the parenthesis it is a class extension. If you define a name then it is a category.

The most common reason to do this is to hide instance variables and methods. To make the appear to be private.