# What's the difference between nameless category and normal categories in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Category and Class Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499704/difference-between-category-and-class-extension)

I am often told that when you want to declare a variable as private you would make a nameless category on the .m file.

Is there anything inherently different in the nameless category as opposed to named categories?

What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Category and Class Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499704/difference-between-category-and-class-extension), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136124/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052233/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you refer to as a 'nameless category' is called a 'class extension'.

One difference is that the compiler expects that declarations in the class extension are defined in the class' `@implementation` block. That is, you do not declare the extension's `@implementation` block explicitly when it is in the same translation as the primary `@implementation` block. They are merged for your convenience. Consequently, the compiler may produce warnings.

Another difference is that an extension may declare properties which are synthesized (and consequently resize the type), where a regular category cannot. In addition to properties, instance variables may be declared in the class extension's `@interface`.

Beyond that, it's just convention.

Comment: Class extensions can also declare ivars, while other categories cannot.

Comment: Oh Class extension can change the size of the type. That's a big thing there. Now I see.